# How to make background fill or flush to the footer at the bottom of the window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

My footer is always at the bottom of my website's content, which is great if there is enough content to push the footer down.  But the background looks awful when there isn't enough content to push the footer at least to the bottom of the window.  Here is what happens **when there is** enough content:

[image: Enough content to fill in space]

Here is what happens **when there's not** enough content:

[image: Not enough content]

How do I make the background stretch to always reach where the footer is?
I'm *not* asking how to make a sticky footer.  I am asking how to make the content's background fill to reach where the sticky footer is.

Here is my css:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

/* This makes the bottom footer sticky. */
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 51px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 51px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


/* box shadow settings.  Don't pay much attention to this. */

.boxshadow-hack {
  text-align: center; /* This hack makes the child div (which is .boxshadow-around-content) centered.  Because the display is inline-block, it is auto left adjusted normally. */
}
.boxshadow-around-content {
  text-align: left; /* This reverses the text-align:center hack that is used to center this div.  We will make adjustments to this class depending on the screen width using media queries, because a box shadow doesn't look good if it's too crammed. */
  display: inline-block;
  background-image:none;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
}

.boxshadow-outer {
  text-align: left; /* This reverses the text-align:center hack that is used to center this div.  We will make adjustments to this class depending on the screen width using media queries, because a box shadow doesn't look good if it's too crammed. */
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

.boxshadow-outer-hack {
  text-align: center; /* This hack makes the child div (which is .boxshadow-around-content) centered.  Because the display is inline-block, it is auto left adjusted normally. */
  width:100%;
  background-image: url("http://i609.photobucket.com/albums/tt178/imanono/cream_dust_zpsqualmncn.png");
}

.boxshadow-hack {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}


.boxshadow-outer {
  padding: 0 15px; /* This changes how far away the box shadow is from the website's content. */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 33px 3px rgba(231,231,231,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 33px 3px rgba(231,231,231,1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 33px 3px rgba(231,231,231,1);
}

.boxshadow-around-content {
  padding: 5 35px; /* This changes how far away the box shadow is from the website's content. */
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(184,184,184,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(184,184,184,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(184,184,184,0.75);
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<body>
    <nav> <!-- top nav stuff here --> </nav>
        <div class="boxshadow-outer-hack">
            <div class="boxshadow-outer">
                <div class="boxshadow-hack">
                    <div class="boxshadow-around-content">
                        <div class="section">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h1 class="text-center">
                                    <b>Title</b>
                                    </h1>
                                    <h2 class="text-center">Second Title</h2>
                                        <!-- Content goes here -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <nav> <!-- footer nav stuff here --> </nav>
<body>
```

[Here is an example when there isn't enough content to fill:](https://heavensgospel.org/about) -https://heavensgospel.org/about It's working now.  Look at update for how I made it work.

[Here is an example when there is enough content to fill:](https://heavensgospel.org/)
https://heavensgospel.org

I was going to use jsfiddle but it can't interpret my code for the sticky footer correctly.  Just copy and paste my code into a local html file to see what my situation is, or go to my link.

**UPDATE**
Veiko's answer is correct but very unsupported.  c01gat3's answer is correct and widely supported but hacky.  I discovered a less-hacky way in my opinion (It's still hacky and frowned upon though).  It uses display: table as a layout and then for the middle content cell, it uses height: auto to fill in the blank space between the head navbar and sticky footer.  I didn't come up with this myself though haha.

```
<style>
#tablecontainer{
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
}

.table-panel {
    display: table;
}
.table-panel > div {
    display: table-row;
}
.table-panel > div.fill {
    height: auto;
}




/* Unimportant styles just to make the demo looks better */
#top-cell {
    height: 50px;
    background-color:aqua;
}
#middle-cell {
  /* nothing here yet */
  background-color:purple;
}
#bottom-cell {
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}




body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
</style>

<body>
    <nav> <!-- top nav stuff here --> </nav>
        <div class="boxshadow-outer-hack">
            <div class="boxshadow-outer">
                <div class="boxshadow-hack">
                    <div class="boxshadow-around-content">
                        <div class="section">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h1 class="text-center">
                                    <b>Title</b>
                                    </h1>
                                    <h2 class="text-center">Second Title</h2>
                                        <!-- Content goes here -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <nav> <!-- footer nav stuff here --> </nav>
<body>
```

Here is a fiddle of the updated method to get the center content to fill in the blank space where the sticky footer is.
https://jsfiddle.net/uzfcvzde/

Comment: Hi, you misread my question. I already have a sticky footer perfectly working if you look at the screenshots.  I am asking how to make the content's background fill the blank space between the top navbar and the footer. @BramVanroy

Comment: I see. Vote to close retracted. However, why don't you simply use the background on `body`? Also, supporting IE6 is madness. If you *really* have to, consider employing graceful degradation, where older browsers don't look *exactly* like the new ones (e.g. no box-shadow) but the core functionality and information is still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add the following property to `.boxshadow-outer` it will work

```
.boxshadow-outer {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 103px);
}
```

This forces the container to be 100% of the viewport height and then subtracts the height of the navbar and footer (103px).

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick clean code, as I would do:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

article,
nav,
footer {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1em;
}

article,
menu {
  max-width: 44em;
  width: 80vw;
}

article {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
menu li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <menu>
      <li>
        Page Title
      </li>
      <li>
        menuItem#1
      </li>
      <li>
        menuItem#2
      </li>
    </menu>
  </nav>
  <article>
    Page Content
  </article>
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Amen!

Comment: This works, is there something that can make the flexbox work in older browsers for this case?

Comment: Hey. If you prefix the css (ex https://autoprefixer.github.io), I think it will work. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Thank you!  This is awesome!  In a few years I may switch to flexbox, but I need to support the chinese who use pirated Windows XP unfortunately.  They are all on IE6.  I am looking into alternatives right now.  The calc() option works but is too hacky for me.  Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

ya i do believe this background stuff it's a bit tricky.

i have some clue for u,

1. set html, body and boxshadow-outer-hack min-height 100% into height 100%
2. set your boxshadow-outer-hack into 100vh

let me explain this, u've got html and body with min-height, it's not good at all because this min-height means if you have a dynamic content (you can add or delete CRUD stuff in content) it will stretch down following how long your content is. But if you set height 100%, it said "oh all of them is counted, including the withe space".

if you set the content div into 100vh it's mean you want this content become same height as the screen device height.

this is not the proper answer i guess, but i just trying to give you a clue.

wish it will help you, GBU son.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, for container we are giving margin-bottom: -100px which is height of footer.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -100px; 
}

.site-footer{
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Hi, content goes here;
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I already know how to get a sticky footer.  I'm asking how to make the background occupy the remaining space below the content, to reach the sticky footer.